# Bootstrap v2.3.2 menu changes size after opening/closing it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

The goal its to have a menu activated by a button.

This menu can have any type of content inside, so it must adapt according to its content.

In this example i have an accordion, but could be just a grid, or a form, since i'm making it as a bootstrap/jquery widget.

The problem is that the menu changes size after opening and closing it several times.

How can i improve it to make it adaptable to content and consistent, regarding that it will accept different contents.

Code
http://jsfiddle.net/fpmsusm5/

Javascript:

```
var button = $('#button');
var dialog = $('#modal');
button.on('click', function () {
    dialog.toggleClass('hide');
    dialog.position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "right-2 bottom",
        of: button
    });
})


$("#openpanel1").on("click", function () {
    var curr_panel = $("#panel1")
    curr_panel.toggleClass('show hide');
    curr_panel.collapse(curr_panel.hasClass('show') ? 'show' :     'hide');
});

...

/* ensure any open panels are closed before showing selected */
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a id="button" class="btn">Settings</a>
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal hide" style="overflow-    y:hidden;width:auto;height:auto;max-height:100%; max-width:100% ">
    <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y:hidden; width:auto;     height:auto; max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
        <div id="accordion">

            <button id="openpanel1" type="button" class="btn"     style="width:100%;text-align:left"><i
                    class="icon-search"></i>Page Information
            </button>
            <div id="panel1" class="collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Contents panel 1
                </div>
            </div>

            ....

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you position the dialog, it's changing the `left` property, and that's causing it to resize.

You don't have to reposition it every time you show/hide it, you can just do it once:

```
var dialog = $('#modal');
dialog.position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right-2 bottom",
    of: button
});
button.on('click', function () {
    dialog.toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Then it stays the same size. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpmsusm5/1/

[image]

Comment: thanks! It fixes the issue, im just wondering why the position its in the center, am i positioning it incorrectly? I expected it to be aligned with the button.

Comment: @dotmindlabs that's odd - it's aligned with the button for me in Chrome - what browser are you using? I'll add a screenshot to my answer for comparison

Comment: Im using Chrome in Ubuntu

Comment: I did notice if I make the window smaller beyond a certain point it moves slightly right for some reason. Let me try on my Mac

Comment: Same deal on Mac - right-aligned until I shrink the window beyond a certain point - see screenshot. I don't have ubuntu handy to investigate further, sorry, but seems strange that there'd be a difference.

Comment: Thanks again, i will keep testing it in different browsers.